# Understand the definition of frame and inertial frame in Arnold's Galilean spacetime definition

Tags: classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

In Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*, we define the physical space time as a four dimensional affine space with associated Galilean structure. I understand this part.

Now what I'm not clear after reading the next section in the book is:

1. What's the definition of a frame of reference, i.e. the formal definition of the mapping from the physical spacetime to $\mathbb{R}^4$. I guess the mapping needs to be bijective and preserving the Galilean structure.
2. What's the definition of an inertial frame? Is it an additional axiom that states there's a special frame mapping? Or does the concept of inertial frame already emerge from the Galilean spacetime definition?

Comment: What is the "Galileian structure"?

Comment: @ValterMoretti As defined in Arnold's book. A Galilean structure is an affine space A^4, plus a time interval linear form t: R^4 -> R, plus a distance metric p: A^3 x A^3 -> R defined only on the kernals of t (simultaneous events)

Comment: The kernel is of $dt$ not $t$...

Comment: Closely related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418363/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769697/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421425/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163560/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the definition of the Galilean structure written in your comment, an **inertial reference frame** can be safely *defined* as a **Cartesian coordinate system** with respect to the affine structure of $A^4$ with origin $O$ and axes $e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3$ such that

(1) $\langle e_0,dt\rangle =1 $

(2) $\langle e_i, dt \rangle = 0$ for $i=1,2,3$.

With these requirements, it is not difficult to prove that, considering a pair of these  Cartesian coordiante systems associated to different choices of the basis and the origin, the transformation laws are, in fact, the **Galilean transformations**

$$x'^0 = x^0 + c \: (= t+k)$$
$$x'^k = c^k+t v^k + \sum_{j=1}^3R^k_j x^j \:, \quad k=1,2,3$$
where
$v^k, c^k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $[R^k_j] \in O(3)$.

A general reference frame $x'^b$ is connected to an inertial one $x^a$ through a generic motion of the non inertial frame with respect to the inertial one:
$$x'^0 = x^0 + c\:,$$
$$x'^k = c^k(t) + \sum_{j=1}^3R^k_j(t) x^j \:, \quad k=1,2,3$$
where
$c^k(t)$ and $[R^k_j](t) \in O(3)$ are arbitrary smooth functions.

Comment: This is a definition of the inertial reference frame, what's the definition for reference frame in general?

Comment: For example, how would a rotating frame of reference be defined?

Comment: It is defined, in coordinates, as the change of coordinates  $x'^0 = x^0 + c \: (= t+k)$ and $x'^k = c^k(t) + \sum_{j=1}^3R(t)^k_j x^j\:, \quad k=1,2,3$ for arbitrary smooth functions $c^k(t)$ and $R(t) \in O(3)$.